# single model to have two file attachment columns - Rails 4 + Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I have a custom model which uses attachment model in rails.
My attachment model looks something like this

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true
  has_attached_file :file, styles: { logo: ['200x50>',:png] }
end
```

and the other model that uses the attachment looks something like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attachments, as: :attachable, dependent: :destroy
end
```

I want user model to have another attachment different from the one I have already setup to upload logo, something like this

```
has_one :user_logo, -> {where attachable_type: "UserLogo"}, class_name: "Attachment", foreign_key: :attachable_id, foreign_type: :attachable_type, dependent: :destroy
```

but when I try to access `attachment.attachable` I get

`undefined UserLogo as **UserLogo** is not a model`.

Can anyone please suggest what changes can I make so that `attachment.attachable` works for both attachment type.

so for example

when i execute something like this

`att = Attachment.find(3)` **#assume it returns attachable type as User
so att.attachable returns user object**

but when i execute
`att = Attachment.find(3)` **#assume it returns attachable type as UserLogo
so att.attachable returns exception `wrong constant name UserLogo`**

how can i access `User` object from both attachment types. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep your attachable type 'User' which will be clean polymorphic. Define **type** field inside 'Attachment' model having two values **logo** & **file**

Association will get updated as below

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :attachments, -> {where type: "file"}, as: :attachable, dependent: :destroy  
has_one :user_logo, -> {where type: "logo"}, class_name: "Attachment", foreign_key: :attachable_id, foreign_type: :attachable_type, dependent: :destroy

end
```

I suggest you to have different styles for attachment depends on what type it have (logo/file). Validation for attachment type also vary as per type.

```
has_attached_file :file, styles: ->(file){ file.instance.get_styles }

validates_attachment_content_type :file, :content_type: [..], if: -> { type == 'logo' }

validates_attachment_content_type :file, :content_type: [..], if: -> { type == 'file' }


def get_styles
  if self.type == 'logo'
    style1
  elsif self.type == 'file'
    style2
  end
end
```

Please update status or any query you u get further.

**Update** - answering to further question

**First Way:** If you are using `UserLogo` as an attachable_type in `Attachment`, then it do not follow polymorphic association so define custom association.

```
belongs_to :resource,
  -> { |attachment| ['User', 'UserLogo'].include? attachment.attachable },
  class_name: 'User',
  foreign_key: :attachable_id

belongs_to :belongs_to :attachable,
  -> { |attachment| ['User', 'UserLogo'].exclude? attachment.attachable_type },
  class_name: :attachable_type,
  foreign_key: :attachable_id
```

**Second Way:** Create `UserLogo` class extending `User` class. It will find UserLogo with same User data

Comment: Hi @ray, thanks for your reply. I still get a exception, i have updated the question with sample example, can you please check? Thanks

Comment: so my main question is how can i access user object when attachment type is logo

Comment: @opensource-developer I have not tried so not pretty sure, but it should work, check update in my answer

Comment: @opensource-developer my pleasure :)